Problem with Database Type in DaoMaster Class in Android Studio
I am very new to Android Studio and I have a problem with DoaMaster Java Class. I have developed a simple app for getting user's input and store them, with an ability to send the stored data via message. I have the following error from android studio in DoaMaster Class, and it seems that the database type is wrong. (Required Type: Database, Provided: SQLite Database). This part of the codes has been used by another Class (AppDataBase.java, public static void initialize). What is the solution?
public class DaoMaster extends AbstractDaoMaster {
    public static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;



    public static void createAllTables(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifNotExists) {
        PlayerDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
        SportDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
        ExerciseDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
        messageDao.createTable(db, ifNotExists);
    }

    public static void dropAllTables(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean ifExists) {
        PlayerDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
        SportDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
        ExerciseDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
        messageDao.dropTable(db, ifExists);
    }

    public static abstract class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public OpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, name, factory, 1);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.i("greenDAO", "Creating tables for schema version 1");
            DaoMaster.createAllTables(db, false);
        }
    }

    public static class DevOpenHelper extends OpenHelper {
        public DevOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
            super(context, name, factory);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " by dropping all tables");
            DaoMaster.dropAllTables(db, true);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
        // Error is here
    public DaoMaster(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super(db, 1);
        registerDaoClass(PlayerDao.class);
        registerDaoClass(SportDao.class);
        registerDaoClass(ExerciseDao.class);
        registerDaoClass(messageDao.class);
    }

    public DaoSession newSession() {
        return new DaoSession(this.db, IdentityScopeType.Session, this.daoConfigMap);
    }

    public DaoSession newSession(IdentityScopeType type) {
        return new DaoSession(this.db, type, this.daoConfigMap);
    }
}

Error Image
When I change the SQLite Database to Database, the Error disappeared, but the error is now in AppDataBase.java, public static void initialize!
